# Laravel SSH: Remote connection [] not defined

Tags: laravel, ssh, laravel-5

My code in routes.php is as follows:

```
Route::get('/pull/{key?}',  array('as' => 'install', function($key = null) {
    if($key == "JfjkGmn7JUIygNHf8jh&ygnfrYub"){
        SSH::run(array(
            'cd /var/www/',
            'git pull https://myusername:mypass@bitbucket.org/mygroup/myrep.git'
        ));
        echo 'Pull from Bitbucket.org is done... Do not forget to migrate though! <a href="/dashboard">Click here to continue</a>';
    } else {
        App::abort(404);
    }
}));
```

But I get the error `InvalidArgumentException in RemoteManager.php line 156:
Remote connection [] not defined.`. Can anyone tell wme where and when to set a connection? It should be local, so my guess was that I do not need to set it.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 there is no more SSH. There is a  separate package for that - [SSH for Laravel 5](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/ssh#) so looking at documentation you need to configure connection in `config/remote.php`. In Laravel 4.2 SSH was built in framework - documentation for [SSH in Laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ssh#configuration)

Comment: OK, thanx. I have this package. in the `remote.php` file there is this section `'connections' => [
   'production' => [
    'host'      => '',
    'username'  => '',
    'password'  => '',
    'key'       => '',
    'keytext'   => '',
    'keyphrase' => '',
    'agent'     => '',
   ],
  ]` Do I here add the bitbucket URL ?

Comment: @AlvinBakker You should look at documentation https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/ssh#basic-usage